# (laravel) how to use unique validation request on update

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to use unique validation in **Lavavel 8** but the problem is that it doesn't allow me to update when I don't change the `name` field

my update code on my `TemplateController`

```
    public function updateTemplate($templateId, TemplateRequest $templateRequest)
    {
        $thumbnailUrl = $this->templateService->updateThumbnail($templateRequest);

        $this->templateRepository->updateTemplateInfo($templateRequest, $templateId, $thumbnailUrl);
        
        return redirect()->route('templates.list.show', [$templateId])
            ->with(["message" => __('templates.edit.success')]);
}
```

this is my `UpdateTemplateInfo` at `TemplateRepository`

```
public function updateTemplateInfo($request, $templateId, $thumbnail)
{
    $template = $this->getTemplate($templateId);
    $template->name = $request->name;
    $template->thumbnail = $thumbnail;
    $template->business_type_id = $request->business_type;
    $template->update();
}
```

and this is my `TemplateRequest`

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|unique:templates',
        'business_type' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

this is the method in `web.php`

```
Route::patch('/list/{templateId}/update', 'TemplateController@updateTemplate')->name('templates.list.update');
```

When I try to update without change the name field, the validator fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a separate request for post and put you can do something like this...

```
public function rules() {
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|unique:templates,name',
        'business_type' => 'required'
    ];

    if ($this->method() === 'PUT') {
        $rules['name'] .= ',' . $this->route('templateId');
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Comment: I get this error, maybe because the ID SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '13' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `templates` where `13` = test-template)

Comment: I forgot the field name. Try the updated code.

Comment: Now I get this error. .  . SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column ' name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `templates` where ` name` = test-template and `id` <> 13)

Comment: templateId value is the id from the table (ex. 13)

Comment: So what field is storing the name value?

Comment: name => name . . . business_type => business_type_id . . . . templateId => id

Comment: Then how are you getting `Unknown column 'name'` if you have a `name` field. You seem to have other issues here.

Comment: my bad, I put a space before name " name"
thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

you should create a new request class for the update case

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => "required|unique:templates,name,{$this->name}",
        'business_type' => 'required'
    ];
}
```

or you can edit the current request class to this:

```php
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'business_type' => 'required'
    ];

    if (request()->method == 'PUT') {
        $rules['name'] = "required|unique:templates,name,{$this->name}";
    } else {
        $rules['name'] = 'required|unique:templates';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```